# implementing a networked multiplayer game loop in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

i am working on a game project and i decide to go with twisted for the server part.

its a multiplayer shooting game.

now i want to integrate a main loop into the game (on server side) to process input and physics(for bullets and players).The inputs are recieved from the clients through websockets.
i want the game loop to run game at lets say. 50 fps.

if i follow the method for implementing a game loop mentioned [in this atricle](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). i have this code below

```
previous = getCurrentTime()

def loop():
    double lag = 0.0
    while True:

      current = getCurrentTime()
      elapsed = current - previous
      previous = current
      lag += elapsed

      processInput()

      while (lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE):
        update()
        lag -= MS_PER_UPDATE
      send_state_to_connected_clients()
```

In the article it mentions that:

> If you’re making a game that runs in a web browser, you pretty much can’t write your own classic game loop. The browser’s event-based nature precludes it

Now i am having a difficult time understanding it as this applies to  ***Twisted*** as it's also event based.***(i think what it says is the `while true` statement will block the reactor forever.so what can we do to implement our own loop in twisted given its even based)***

in the same article towards the bottom it mentions these points:

> Use the platform’s event loop:
>   1. It’s simple. You don’t have to worry about writing and optimizing the core loop of the game 
>   2. It plays nice with the platform. You don’t have to worry about explicitly giving the host time to process its own events, caching events, or otherwise managing the impedance mismatch between the platform’s input model and yours.

What i am looking for is a general approach towards implementing a game loop in twisted(for a networked multiplayer game).

- should i use the inbuilt reactor by using the [LoopingCall](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html) to call 
  my `Loop`? how does then it handles the issues
  mentioned in the article.
- should i create my own loop somehow? (ex by using threads/processes or some other construct to run the game loop seperate from reactor)
- should i create my own reactor implementation somehow?

Comment: You can find an example of this in https://code.launchpad.net/game

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone thanks, i had stumbled upon this previously while searching for answers. i looked into network.py file https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~game-hackers/game/trunk/view/head:/game/network.py but couldn't find relevant information. i wanted to integrate a game loop into the twisted reactor

Comment: The simulation loop is integrated with the event loop in https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~game-hackers/game/trunk/view/head:/game/environment.py

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem accurately, you will have a Python server and players will play a real-time FPS in the browser. You will have to:

- display the game in real-time
- handle user events in the browser
- send browser-event results to the server
- parse the results on the server
- send server events to the browser
- handle server events in the browser

We already know that you are going to use WebSockets.

### Display the game in real-time

You will need to display the graphics somewhere, maybe inside a canvas. You will need to implement lots of functions, like update health bar, display changes and so on. These will be triggered when you handle responses from the server.

### Handle user events in the browser

If we assume that clicking is shooting, space is activate and so on, you will need some event handlers for those. In the browser you will need a browser-level validation. For instance, if the player intends to shoot, but there is no more ammo, then you do not even have to send a message to the server, maybe display a sound effect of the gun which signifies that shooting was unsuccessful. If, according to the data you have in the browser you have ammo, then the direction you shoot at should be sent to the server.

### Send browser-event results to the server

When an event occurs in the browser and is evaluated, then the results in many cases will be sent to the server, which will handle them and eventually send a response to the browser.

### Parse the results on the server

The server will have an event loop and will receive WebSocket messages from the browsers of the players. For example if the server receives a shoot event, then it will get the current coordinates of the player and the direction, calculate where the bullet goes and send a message to the players' browser. If someone is hit, then damage is to be calculated and determined whether the player dies, subsequently players will get WebSocket messages from the server and subsequently the sound of the bullet will be displayed along with the bullet's graphical display and potentially some blood, falling players and so on.

### Send server events to the browser

The browsers will listen to WebSocket messages from the server and handle those.

### Handle server events in the browser

We cannot trust user events, because some cheating could be involved, so when you shoot, the browser will handle the event and the server will receive a message. When the server sends a WebSocket message, the browsers will "believe" that the server sent an accurate response.

### Technical needs

You will need a graphics API, user event listeners and WebSocket listeners in the browsers. On the server you will listen to client WebSocket messages.

Comment: thankyou for your answer but i am familiar with all the aspects, my question is very specific to implementing a game loop for an event based system ,in  my case its twisted. i am looking for some primitive that twisted provides so that i can implement a game loop on my server

Comment: @anekix you can implement an event loop as you wish on your server. It has Threads and so on. However, the event loop problem is on browser-side. I think it would be great if you had a queue on the server which would receive events from browsers and handle them. Since twisted is on server-side and your problem is on browser side, the two are running on different computers. Your server does not necessarily have to know about browsers being used, only about the WebSocket messages.

Comment: @LajosArpand . twisted has its event loop to handle networked events(ex when some packet is recieved on a socket). what i am asking is a game has to have its own loop to calculate physics.it should be present on server side. i do not have issues with browser side ,i can handle that. how should i integrate my gameloop in twisted event loop is what i am confused about

Comment: @anekix you create a queue where you push items when browsers send data or some event happens. In  your forever loop each time you can pull an item from the queue and handle it.

Comment: yes that is the way to handle events but what i am asking is how to write a game loop itself, assuming there are 10 players i need to calculate the positions of bullets and players, that is done in a game loop. how do i integrate gameloop in twisted

Comment: @anekix first of all you will need a state where you store where the players are, how much health they have, how many bullets they have, where are the paths and obstacles. On each step of the loop you can pull an item from the queue and handle it, by calculating the result according to the current state and update the state, finally send a WebSocket message to the browsers to update their states as well.

Comment: its not as straigh forward as it seems. initially i had it implemented as the way you said but waht if i want to simulate gravity /acceleration?when should i do the iteration ? it wont work if i wait for some input event to be sent to the server and so the next step calculation. so i need a running game loop which is able to handle all my connect payers at 50fps.even if some players have slow machines  the game state needs to be same

Comment: @anekix the gravity acceleration seems to be a different Thread on your server. It would be opened when the player starts to fall and closed when the player finishes falling. The thread would generate events, which would be added to the event queue. In order to achieve this you will need to make sure that your threads have access to the event queue. These threads would periodically generate a message, every n milliseconds.

Comment: thankyou so much for help but i am not sure you are getting my point. all i want is the game loop that i gave above to be integrated into twisted .i need a game loop to maintain frame rate independence

Comment: @anekix understood. I wish you the best of luck to achieve the integration you aim to achieve.